# Returning decoded data of multiple types not working

Tags: arrays, json, swift, switch-statement, nsuserdefaults

I am downloading data from Firebase and storing into UserDefaults.  I am encoding and decoding it properly, and I can retrieve the data once its decoded.  The problem I am stuck on is how to "return" any of the save values when needed.  The struct I used to store that data contains 3 different types of value types: `Bool` `String` and `Int`.

There are parts of my app where I am going to need to retrieve any one of the different value types, depending on the scenario.  I wrote a function that I was hoping to use to pull data from the decoded object when needed. Since the data is already saved as the correct value type.  I can't seem to find a way to make the "return" change or be agnostic depending on the value type.  I did some reading on Generics in Swift, but I am still unsure if that is the right solution.    I have outlined my code below to explain further.  Any suggestions or solutions would be much appreciated.

This function below is what I am referring to where I am stuck.  I put the return type as Any, to experiment and see what would happen. Its not working right since the data is already formatted with the correct type so when I retrieve it using `Any` it would need me to convert it back to a `String` `Bool` or `Int`.  Additionally, the `data: UserData` is an enum I made to allow selection, so that I could use dot notation to select whichever item I would want.

```
    static func getUserInfo(data: UserData) -> Any { **// <- Return type here, also data is an enum below**
        if let savedPerson = defaults.object(forKey: "userInfo") as? Data {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let specificUser = try? decoder.decode(User.self, from: savedPerson) {                
                switch data {
                case .number:
                    return specificUser.mobile
                case .name:
                    return specificUser.mobile
                case .pictureUrl:
                    return specificUser.pictureUrl!
                case .accountType:
                    return specificUser.accountType
                case .isEmailVarified:
                    return specificUser.isEmailVarified
                default:
                break
                }
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Here is the UserData enum:

```
enum UserData {
    case number
    case name
    case pictureUrl
    case accountType
    case isEmailVarified
}
```

Here is the command I was intended to use to "retrieve" whatever option I wanted

```
let number = SaveToDefaults.getUserInfo(data: .mobile) as! String
myLabel.text = number
```

EDIT:

Here is the original struct that that all of the data is retrieved from Firebase with and then encoded into UserDefaults

```
struct User: Encodable, Decodable {
    var uid: String
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var mobile: String
    var pictureUrl: String?
    var accountType: AccountType!
    var token: String?
    var stripeId: String?
    var pending: PendingStatus?
    var isEmailVarified: Bool?

    init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
        self.mobile = dictionary["mobile"] as? String ?? ""
        self.pictureUrl = dictionary["pictureUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        
        if let index = dictionary["accountType"] as? Int {
            self.accountType = AccountType(rawValue: index)
        }
        
        self.token = dictionary["token"] as? String ?? ""
        self.stripeId = dictionary["stripe_id"] as? String ?? ""
        
        if let pendingUser = dictionary["pendingUser"] as? Int {
            self.pending= PendingStatus(rawValue: accountonline)
        }
        if let driverstatus = dictionary["isDriverPending"] as? Int {
            self.driverPendingStatus = DriverStatus(rawValue: driverstatus)
        }
        self.isEmailVerified = false
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem that you're having?  The code you have shared works, although it would probably be easier just to return the whole struct with the 5 fields unless there's a specific reason why that won't work

Comment: Agreed with @Russell. You're trying to make it too complex.  Return the whole struct (you're decoding it already) and then just access the property required at the time: `let number = SaveToDefaults.getUserInfo().mobile`. This is type safe rather than using Any (which is always best avoided), avoids any forced casts, and is generally far simpler.

Comment: Thank you for both this advise.  That makes sense, you are correct.  Do you recommend that I return it to an array and just choose the option I need?  I assume it has to confirm to my User struct, which is what it was encoded with.  I was worried about putting into an array as I didn't want to have it all over the place

Answer (score 0):

There are some languages, like PHP, which let you return any data type in a single function.  Generally speaking, languages that allow this get a bad reputation for maintainability.

That disclaimer out of the way:

If you’re really just displaying the result as a String on the screen, there’s probably nothing inherently evil in using your case statement to cast each value as a string and return that.

E.g.

```
case .isEmailVarified:
    return String(specificUser.isEmailVarified)  // EDITED to include a non-String variable after you EDITED your question to include struct.
```

EDIT:

I agree with the other commenters who say passing the Struct around instead of individual values is a good thing.  One trick you could try, assuming you can target iOS 14, is to take advantage of the new @AppStorage construct instead of userDefaults. This might just be personal preference on my part, but the below feels pretty legible.

```
  @AppStorage("user") var user = ""

  // to persist your object as JSON string
  let u = try! JSONEncoder().encode(userObjectFromFirebase)
  result = String(data: u, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
  self.user = result

  // to fetch your object as User object
  let u = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: self.user.data(using: .utf8)!)

  // reference your values
  myLabel.text = u.number
  myLabel2.text = String(u.isEmailVerified)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise.  So there are Bools and Int's in there from other enums.  Also, the user data structs is not the struct it was put into the array.  I could use from the variables, but because they could clear out, I preferred user defaults.  The problem is, not all of the data are strings

Comment: I updated with the struct that I am using to bring the data in

Comment: updated my response to reference how I would handle your non-String fields now that I can see your actual struct.  Also added some suggestions about how to return the full user struct easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, it does make a lot of sense.  One final question; does the solution you you proposed work outside of SwiftUI?  I am utilizing IOS14, but not SwiftUI yet.

Comment: It's SwiftUI only, *but*, you should be able to mix and match SwiftUI code with AppKit code. e.g. https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/swiftui-mix-and-match/

Totally up to you. I could argue either side.  Start migrating to SwiftUI over time makes sense since it's the future direction and you'll probably have to eventually if your app lives long enough.  Or don't because mixing programming paradigms in the same app can be confusing!